# ABAP Web Dynpro Employee Search Help

Tags: abap, web, dynpro

One input field is employeenumber (pernr). I want to give a selection window to allow end users to get pernr by first name and last name. What I want is very similar to the inputfield in transaction pa20. See the screenshot below. Can anyone give me some hints? I am very new to ABAP and WDA. [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In WDA you can assign a specific search help to a context attribute without any coding.

So find out which search help is the one available at PA20 (or create your own at SE11), and assign it to the context attribute in your WDA component.

[image: Example of context in WDA context screen]